# The image path in the database is not saved

Tags: php, laravel

I want to upload a photo along with a text

### But the photo path is not saved inside the table, but the photo is uploaded to the directory

Controller code

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers;
use App\Http\Requests\singlereq;
use App\infouser;
class singleupload extends Controller
{
    public function uploadform()
    {
        return view('singleupload.upload_form');
    }
    public function uploadSubmit(singlereq $request)
    {
        $file = $request->file('imgs');
        $file->move('img', $file->getClientOriginalName()); 
        $product = infouser::create($request->all());
        return 'OK Upload successful!';
    }
}
```

Comment: In the product is the name of the product is `imgs`

Comment: The name of the product is
And Field img for product

Comment: So rename the input file name to `img` and here to `$file = $request->file('imgs');` must be `$file = $request->file('img');` and tested !!

Comment: You should just save the name of the image with extension and when you will access the image for showing purpose, then you can add folder_name/image_name, where image_name will come from database, for better way you can write a function in infouser modal file to fetch the image.

Answer (score 1):

Used below code. to get the image name and set the table column (your_file) your is column name in your table.

```
$file = $request->file('imgs');
$file->move('img', $file->getClientOriginalName()); 
$input = $request->all();
$name = $file->getClientOriginalName();
$input['your_file'] = $name; 
$product = infouser::create($input);
return 'OK Upload successful!';
```

Comment: Excellent. Thank you.